# Stuck "Retriving API Listings" adding Google API's to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-drive-api

I am trying to add the Google Drive API to eclipse using the Google Plugin, following the instructions of the quickstart guide here: [Google Drive SDK Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android). However, when I click the "Add Google APIs" item from the dropdown menu (of the google plugin icon), the new API popup gets stuck on "Retrieving API Listings" and just displays a blank list. Tried leaving it for 30 minutes, re-installing the plugin, restarting eclipse and computer, but to no avail.

Eclipse Version: 4.2.2

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there another way to obtain/install the Drive API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Java library for the Drive API (and any other Google APIs) from the project hosting website:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API